# How to return interface using generic in C#

Tags: c#, generic-programming

I am new in C# Generic concept and I would like to return interface implemented class using generic concept. Below is my example which is currently implemented without generic:

1) Factory Class which return interface and this class has two overload method which accept different data model:

```
public class Factory
{
    public ICommon Init(DBInfoData dbInfoData)
    {
        return new ClassA(dbInfoData);
    }

    public ICommon Init(WebInfoData webInfoData)
    {
        return new ClassB(webInfoData);
    }
}
```

2) Interface and interface implemented two class as below:

```
//=== Common Interface
public interface ICommon
{
    void MethodA();
    void MethodB();
}

//=== Internal access only ClassA
internal class ClassA : ICommon
{
    private DBInfoData _DBInfoData = null;
    public ClassA(DBInfoData dbInfoData)
    {
        _DBInfoData = dbInfoData;
    }

    public void MethodA()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

//=== Internal access only ClassB
internal class ClassB : ICommon
{
    private WebInfoData _WebInfoData = null;

    public ClassB(WebInfoData webInfoData)
    {
        _WebInfoData = webInfoData;
    }

    public void MethodA()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

3) Data Model class as below:

```
//=== Database Information
public class DBInfoData
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
}

//=== Web Server Information
public class WebInfoData
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to implement generic functionality of C# where in factory class I do not want to declare two overload method. Using single method I can return ClassA or ClassB based on Data Model pass.

Comment: How did you call `Factory` methods right now? Do you have only two data models, or it'll be more of them?

Comment: "I do not want to declare two overload methods". Why is that? The code you showed us is clean and easily understandable. I can't see what there is to gain from using generics in this case. Did you leave out some parts in the `Factory` where there is duplicated code you want to get rid of?

Comment: Second @GeorgPatscheider's comment. There's nothing to be gained by generics here unless there's something you haven't shared. Stick with overloading.

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider: As told that would like to implement Generic concept which will reduce overload method and and by single method can bind appropriate class. There is nothing part I have miss in Factory code. I like to bind class based on data model so I am looking how can I implement Generic concept in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could edit the `Init` method without having to edit anything else. This method will take a generic type parameter `T`, which can be of any type. Then you can use the `is` operator, which according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) used to type testing. You need to check however for any unsupported type of `T`, because you didn't add any constraint to the generic type passed. A raw implementation would be:

```cs
public class Factory
{
    public ICommon Init<T>(T infoData)
    {
        if (infoData is DBInfoData dbInfoData) {
            return new ClassA(dbInfoData);
        }
        if (infoData is WebInfoData webInfoData) {
            return new ClassB(webInfoData);
        }

        throw new Exception($"Cannot create instance for info data of type {infoData.GetType().Name}");
    }
}
```

And to test it:

```cs
    var factory = new Factory();

    var t1 = factory.Init(new DBInfoData()); // will be ClassA
    var t2 = factory.Init(new WebInfoData()); // ClassB
```

To sophisticate it, you could introduce [type constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) on your generic `T` class to make sure you can only pass appropriate types. For the current situation, you could create a [marker interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) for your classes `DBInfoData` and `WebInfoData` by introducing an empty interface say `IInfoData`. Then you have to inherit your classes like this:

```cs
public interface IInfoData {}

public class DBInfoData : IInfoData
{
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
}

public class WebInfoData : IInfoData
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
}
```

Now both inherits from (actually 'marked by') your base interface. Introduce a constraint to your factory to allow only descendants of `IInfoData` to be passed as an argument (so either `DBInfoData` or `WebInfoData`) by adding a constraint shown in the docs I linked above:

```cs
public class Factory
{
    public ICommon Init<T>(T infoData) where T: IInfoData
    {
        if (infoData is DBInfoData dbInfoData) {
            return new ClassA(dbInfoData);
        }
        if (infoData is WebInfoData webInfoData) {
            return new ClassB(webInfoData);
        }

        throw new Exception($"Cannot create instance for info data of type {infoData.GetType().Name}");
    }
}
```

Any type other than the descendants of `IInfoData` will cause a compilation error, and you're done. Use it like in my previous example:

```cs
    var factory = new Factory();

    var t1 = factory.Init(new DBInfoData()); // will be ClassA
    var t2 = factory.Init(new WebInfoData()); // ClassB
```

Comment: Whilst this works, it violates the SOLID principles, as if you introduce a new implementation of `IInfoData`, you need to update your `Init` method. With this said, your code isn't really generic at all; it is a number of specific implementations, hidden behind a generic interface.

Comment: Yes, just as the factory pattern itself sort of violates SOLID principles if implemented as it's meant to be. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/302780/does-the-factory-pattern-violate-the-open-closed-principle